# how to do imageView touch event under the scrollview?

Tags: objective-c

I am using `- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`  touch method in `imageView` but I have taken `imageView` under the `scrollview` thats why touch event not perform because it is take directly scrollview

My code is

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    // get touch event
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    if ([touch view] == imagedisplay) {
        // move the image view
        imagedisplay.center = touchLocation;
    }


}
```

imagedisplay my imageView object but in not work touch event I have work in scrollview in that taken imageView so give any solution and source code related touch which apply in both scrollview and imageView

Answer (score 0):

use below code, where you are creating imageView-

```
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

As it is `NO` by default.